# Mismatched type for a Linked binary tree and program

Tags: java, string, tree, binary-tree

I have an Instance I cannot change, a class I could but might be better not to, and the main class that actually runs the program.
 At certain parts in the code there is an error between my `LinkedBinaryTreeNode.java` and `java.lang.string`, or I guess the `String` type. these errors can be found on the commented lines.
 I don't know how to fix it or really what it actually means as I am a programming novice. Any help is appreciated.

```java
import java.util.List;


 public interface BinaryTreeNode<E> {


    public E getData();


    public void setData(E data);


    public BinaryTreeNode<E> getRoot();


    public BinaryTreeNode<E> getParent();


    public BinaryTreeNode<E> getLeft();


    public void setLeft(BinaryTreeNode<E> child);


    public BinaryTreeNode<E> getRight();


    public void setRight(BinaryTreeNode<E> child);


    public boolean isParent( );


    public boolean isLeaf( );


    public boolean hasLeftChild( );


    public boolean hasRightChild( );


    public int getDepth( );


    public int getHeight( );


    public int size( );


    public void removeFromParent();


    public List<BinaryTreeNode<E>> pathTo( BinaryTreeNode<E> descendant );


    public List<BinaryTreeNode<E>> pathFrom( BinaryTreeNode<E> ancestor );


    public void traversePreorder(Visitor visitor);


    public void traversePostorder(Visitor visitor);


    public void traverseInorder(Visitor visitor);


    public interface Visitor {
       public void visit(BinaryTreeNode node);
    }
}
```

```java
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Stack;

public class LinkedBinaryTreeNode<E> implements BinaryTreeNode<E> {
    E data;
    BinaryTreeNode<E> parent;
    BinaryTreeNode<E> leftChild;
    BinaryTreeNode<E> rightChild;
    int depth = 0;


    @Override
    public E getData() {
        return data;
    }


    @Override
    public void setData(E data) {
        this.data = data;
    }


    @Override
    public BinaryTreeNode<E> getRoot() {
        BinaryTreeNode<E> currentNode = this;
        if ( currentNode.getParent() != null ) {
            currentNode.getParent().getRoot();
        }
        return currentNode;
    }


    @Override
    public BinaryTreeNode<E> getParent() {
        return parent;
    }

    private void setParent( BinaryTreeNode<E> parent ) {
        this.parent = parent;
    }

    @Override
    public BinaryTreeNode<E> getLeft() {
        return leftChild;
    }


    @Override
    public void setLeft(BinaryTreeNode<E> child) {
        leftChild = child;
        if ( child != null ) {
            ((LinkedBinaryTreeNode<E>) child).setParent(this);
            ((LinkedBinaryTreeNode<E>) child).depth = depth + 1;
        }
    }


    @Override
    public BinaryTreeNode<E> getRight() {
        return rightChild;
    }


    @Override
    public void setRight(BinaryTreeNode<E> child) {
        rightChild = child;
        if ( child != null ) {
            ((LinkedBinaryTreeNode<E>) child).setParent(this);
            ((LinkedBinaryTreeNode<E>) child).depth = depth + 1;
        }
    }


    @Override
    public boolean isParent() {
        return hasLeftChild() || hasRightChild();
    }


    @Override
    public boolean isLeaf() {
        return !isParent();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasLeftChild() {
        return leftChild != null;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean hasRightChild() {
        return rightChild != null;
    }


    @Override
    public int getDepth() {
//        int depth = 0;
//        BinaryTreeNode<E> currentNode = this;
//        while ( currentNode.getParent() != null ) {
//            currentNode = currentNode.getParent();
//            depth++;
//        }
        return depth;
    }


    @Override
    public int getHeight() {
        final int[] height = {0};
        BinaryTreeNode<E> root = getRoot();
        root.traversePreorder( node -> {
            int depth = node.getDepth();
            if ( height[0] < depth ) {
                height[0] = depth;
            }
        } );
        return height[0];
    }


    @Override
    public int size() {
        final int[] size = {0};
        traversePreorder( node -> {
            size[0]++;
        });
        return size[0];
    }


    @Override
    public void removeFromParent() {
        if ( getParent() != null ) {
            if ( getParent().getLeft() == this ) {
                getParent().setLeft( null );
            } else {
                getParent().setRight( null );
            }
            setParent( null );
        }
    }


    @Override
    public List<BinaryTreeNode<E>> pathTo(BinaryTreeNode<E> descendant) {
        List<BinaryTreeNode<E>> pathFrom = descendant.pathFrom( this );
        Stack<BinaryTreeNode<E>> stack = new Stack<>();
        for( BinaryTreeNode<E> node : pathFrom ) {
            stack.push( node );
        }
        List<BinaryTreeNode<E>> pathTo = new ArrayList<>();
        while( !stack.isEmpty() ) {
            pathTo.add( stack.pop() );
        }
        return pathTo;
    }


    @Override
    public List<BinaryTreeNode<E>> pathFrom(BinaryTreeNode<E> ancestor) {
        BinaryTreeNode<E> currentNode = this;
        List<BinaryTreeNode<E>> pathFrom = new ArrayList<>();
        while( currentNode != null && currentNode != ancestor ) {
            pathFrom.add( currentNode );
            currentNode = currentNode.getParent();
        }
        if ( currentNode == null ) {
            return new ArrayList<>();
        }
        pathFrom.add( currentNode );
        return pathFrom;
    }


    @Override
    public void traversePreorder(Visitor visitor) {
        visitor.visit( this );
        if ( hasLeftChild() ) getLeft().traversePreorder( visitor );
        if ( hasRightChild() ) getRight().traversePreorder( visitor );
    }

    @Override
    public void traversePostorder(Visitor visitor) {
        if ( hasLeftChild() ) getLeft().traversePostorder( visitor );
        if ( hasRightChild() ) getRight().traversePostorder( visitor );
        visitor.visit( this );
    }


    @Override
    public void traverseInorder(Visitor visitor) {
        if ( hasLeftChild() ) getLeft().traverseInorder( visitor );
        visitor.visit( this );
        if ( hasRightChild() ) getRight().traverseInorder( visitor );
    }
}
```

```java
import javax.swing.*;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.*;

public class Program4_v2 extends JFrame {   //extending Jframe for visual tree

    private static void write(LinkedBinaryTreeNode<String> root, String path){
        File file=new File(path);
        try (PrintWriter writer=new PrintWriter(file)){
            root.traversePreorder(node -> {
                if(node.getParent()==null){
                    writer.print(node.getData());
                }
                else{
                    writer.print("\n"+node.getData());
                }
            });
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    public static void add(BinaryTreeNode<String> oldNode, String data) {       //if statements helping to determine if there are more nodes


        BinaryTreeNode<String> newNode = new LinkedBinaryTreeNode<>(data); // failing line


        if (oldNode.hasLeftChild() && oldNode.getLeft().getData().contains("Q:")) {
            add(oldNode.getLeft(), data);
        } else if (oldNode.hasRightChild() && oldNode.hasLeftChild() && oldNode.getRight().getData().contains("Q")) {
            add(oldNode.getRight(), data);
        } else if (!oldNode.hasLeftChild() && oldNode.getData().contains("Q")) {
            oldNode.setLeft(newNode);
        } else if (!oldNode.hasRightChild() && oldNode.getData().contains("Q")) {
            oldNode.setRight(newNode);
        } else {
            boolean finished = false;
            BinaryTreeNode<String> node = oldNode.getParent();
            while (oldNode.getParent().getRight() != node) {
                if (node.getData().contains("A:")) {
                    node = node.getParent();
                } else if (!node.hasRightChild() && node.getData().contains("Q")) {
                    finished = true;
                    node.setRight(newNode);
                    break;
                } else if (node.getRight().getData().contains("A:") || node.getRight() == oldNode) {
                    node = node.getParent();
                } else {
                    finished = true;
                    add(node.getRight(), data);
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (!finished) {        //if there are more nodes, find them
                if (!node.hasRightChild()) {
                    node.setRight(newNode);
                } else {
                    add(node.getRight(), data);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    private static LinkedBinaryTreeNode<String>load(String path){


        LinkedBinaryTreeNode<String>root=new LinkedBinaryTreeNode<>(null); // failing line


        try {
            Scanner file = new Scanner(new File(path));
            String string = file.nextLine();


            root=new LinkedBinaryTreeNode<>(string); // failing line


            while(file.hasNext()){
                string=file.nextLine();
                add(root,string);
            }
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return root;
    }
    private static String question(String question){
        System.out.println(question);
        Scanner scanner=new Scanner(System.in);
        String object=scanner.nextLine();
        if (object.contains("?")){
            return "Q:"+object;
        }
        else{
            return "A:"+object;
        }
    }
    private static void question(LinkedBinaryTreeNode<String>node){
        System.out.println(node.getData().substring(2));
        Scanner scanner=new Scanner(System.in);     //scanner in to along for computer to learn
        String string=scanner.next();
        if (string.contains("no")&& node.isLeaf()){
            String object= question("What was the correct answer?");        //printed text for when computer guesses wrong
            String question=question("What is the difference between "+node.getData().substring(2)+" and "+object.substring(2)+"?");
            String answer=question("What is the correct answer?");


            LinkedBinaryTreeNode<String>oldObject=new LinkedBinaryTreeNode<>(node.getData()); // failing line
            LinkedBinaryTreeNode<String>newObject=new LinkedBinaryTreeNode<>(object()); // failing line


            node.setData(question);
            if (answer.contains("yes")){
                node.setRight(newObject);
                node.setLeft(oldObject);
            }
            else{
                node.setRight(newObject);
                node.setLeft(oldObject);
            }
        }
        else if (string.contains("no")){
            question((LinkedBinaryTreeNode)node.getLeft());
        }
        else if (string.contains("yes")&& node.isLeaf()){       //you, or the computer, did it
            System.out.println("Excellent");
        }
        else{
            question((LinkedBinaryTreeNode)node.getRight());
        }
    }
    static JFrame frame;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("20-Questions Game!");       //launching game
        LinkedBinaryTreeNode<String>root=load(args[0]);
        boolean play=true;
        while(play){
            System.out.println("Play?");        //asking to play
            Scanner scanner=new Scanner(System.in);
            if (scanner.next().equals("no")){       //you dont want to play! abort!
                play=false;
            }
            else{
                question(root);
            }
        }
        write(root,"20questions.data");     //writing game to new directory for future playing
        frame=new JFrame("20 Questions");
        JPanel panel=new TreeDisplayPanel(root);
        frame.add(panel);
        frame.setSize(1600,900);
        frame.show();
    }
}

What should be expected is a twenty-questions game that the program helps you make by sort-of playing. a GUI is also supposed to pop up but should work fine and seems unrelated to the problem
```

Comment: Please add pointers to where the error creating lines are.

Comment: I added some asterisks and made some space around the problem lines.

Comment: I personally think it would be better if you added a statement "Lines that start with asterisks are lines that cause errors."

Comment: Edited OP to display the failing lines of codes via comments. Also refactored the usage of `ArrayList` to `List` -> using an implementation DS (specifically as a return value of a method and hard-coded in an API) is a bad practice.

Comment: What errors are you receiving exactly? Compilation errors? Linting errors? Please provide an error output in the OP. Thanks!

Comment: the errors are that "LinkedBinaryTreeNode( ) in LinkedBinaryTreeNode cannot be applied to (java.lang.String)" or "LinkedBinaryTreeNode( ) in LinkedBinaryTreeNode cannot be applied to (null)" depending on the line.